# setDisplayOrientation changes upon onResume()

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera

I'm using the camera and I have it in portrait mode for my app by

```
camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

when the activity goes into the background and comes back the display orientation is back to 0 aka Landscape, but when I try to setDisplayOrientation(90) again it fails and throws an error (possibly because it is final).

How do I maintain the camera being in portrait aka 90degrees mode?

Also I have to support 2.2 and higher so I can only use API 8

Comment: I had it being updated in the wrong location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the Android API documentation, prior to API level 14 you are not allowed to set the orientation while preview is active:
[setDisplayOrientation() reference.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29)

I'm guessing you need to call `stopPreview()`, set the desired orientation, and then call `startPreview()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it to be portrait use the Manifest.xml file to declare the activity as portrait only in the activity tag put:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```